# Rails 3.0.x AJAX question

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is probably a very simple question to answer. i am new to Rails and am having difficulty figuring out something that I am certain is trivial. I have a simple link_to "Show" which is remote and works great. However once i click a remote link and the content is displayed into/from my partial I cannot seem to update that content by clicking again on another link. My server logs are showing the correct calls being made so I believe there must be something wrong I am doing with the callback. Maybe this has something to do with my :locals assignment in my partial. to better understand here is my code...

application.js

```
$(function() {
    $("#showreqs a").live("click", function() {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

_showreq.html.erb (very simple to prove concept)

```
<%= @project.name %>
```

show.js.erb

```
$("#showreq").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'showreq', :locals => { :project => @project}) %>")
```

projects.html.erb (only section that matters)

```
<div id="showreqs">
    <%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <p>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %> 
    Owner: <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'name'), :class => 'genForm_dropBox' %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Project" %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
    <ol>
    <% @projects.each do |t| %>
        <li>
        <%= t.name %> - Owner: <%=  t.user.name %> - 
        <%= link_to "Show", t, :action => "show",  :remote => true %>
         |  
        <%= link_to "delete", t, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?", :title => "Delete" %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    </ol>
</div>
```

projectscontroller (very ugly and will clean)

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @title = "Requirements" 
        @users = User.order("created_at").all
        @project = Project.new
        @projects = Project.all
    end

    def show
        @users = User.order("created_at").all
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @projects = Project.all
    end

    def create
        @project = Project.new(params[:project])
        if (defined?(@project_e)).nil?
            @project_e = Project.new(params[:project])
        end

        if @project.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully created a Project."
            redirect_to projects_path
        else
            flash[:error] = "You made some errors"
            redirect_to projects_path
        end
    end


    def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            flash[:success] = "Project updated."
            redirect_to projects_path
        else
            flash[:error] = "You made some errors"
            redirect_to projects_path
        end
    end

    def destroy
        Project.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "Project destroyed."
        redirect_to projects_path
    end

end
```

If you need any other code such as routes let me know but i assumed my routes and everything else is fine since this does works when "show" link is first clicked.

Comment: can you show the showreq partial?  `replaceWith` will replace the whole node, if the #showreq element is outside the partial, it will be overwritten and no longer exist after the first load.

Comment: the showreq partial is the _mypartial.html.erb ill edit it now to be more clear. OOOhhhhhhh so your saying I am essentially replacing the container I tend to reuse. That makes sense let me make sure. Sorry for troubling you, I am just learning and it turns out I made a non-rails mistake. Thanks again

Comment: I replaced .replaceWith with .html and it works fine. Thanks! I wish i could give u a checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$('#showreq').html()` over `replaceWith`, as what's happening is the #showreq id is being overwritten because it exists outside the partial